# Can't add linker flag to cocoa pods spec

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors, cocoapods

I need to include in my cocoa pods spec option to pass the `-lz` flag in `Other linker flags` section.

For this I tried to use:

```
"compiler_flags" : "-lz"
```

or

```
"compiler_flags" : [
    "-lz"
]
```

but flag doesn't appear in build settings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your full pod file

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding this section in my podspec

[image]